# Spring Data JPA findById() throwing ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, option-type, classcastexception

I have a method that is using `findById()` method of Spring Data JPA. However, this method is returning `ClassCastException` on line number 1 of the getSupportedKey() method where I am calling findById():

```
MySupportedKey cannot be cast to java.util.Optional

private MySupportedKey getSupportedKey(String tenant, String key) {
        Optional<MySupportedKey> mySupportedKeyOptional = mySupportedKeyRepository.findById(new MySupportedKeyId(tenant, key));
        MySupportedKey mySupportedKey= null;
        if(mySupportedKeyOptional !=null) {
             mySupportedKey= mySupportedKeyOptional.orElse(null);
        }
        return mySupportedKey;
    }
```

I have been beating my head for a long time but I am not getting anything. Please help me in getting this resolved. I am using **spring-data-jpa: 2.0.8.RELEASE**.

Adding the Repository Source Code:

```
public interface MySupportedKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<MySupportedKey, MySupportedKeyId> {

List<MySupportedKey> findByIdTenant(@NotNull String tenant);
}
```

Adding the complete stack trace of error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.service.user.entity.MySupportedKey cannot be cast to java.util.Optional
at com.test.service.user.repository.MySupportedKeyRepository$MockitoMock$1304362870.findById(Unknown Source)
at com.test.service.user.repository.MySupportedKeyRepository$MockitoMock$1304362870.findById(Unknown Source)
at com.test.service.user.userpreferences.PreferencesServiceImpl.getSupportedKey(PreferencesServiceImpl.java:217)
at com.test.service.user.userpreferences.PreferencesServiceImpl.updateUserPreferences(PreferencesServiceImpl.java:167)
at com.test.service.user.userpreferences.PreferencesServiceImpl.lambda$2(PreferencesServiceImpl.java:92)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at com.test.service.user.userpreferences.PreferencesServiceImpl.updateUserPreferences(PreferencesServiceImpl.java:92)
at com.test.service.user.preferences.PreferencesServiceImplTest.updateUserPreferences(PreferencesServiceImplTest.java:300)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluateSafely(JUnitRule.java:52)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:43)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.evaluate(RunPrepareTestInstanceCallbacks.java:64)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringFailOnTimeout.evaluate(SpringFailOnTimeout.java:87)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.ProfileValueChecker.evaluate(ProfileValueChecker.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule$TestContextManagerCacheEvictor.evaluate(SpringClassRule.java:230)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace (formatted as code not as a quote if I may ask). And indicate the line in your code where this occurs. Also please include the source code for your repository.

Comment: @JensSchauder Added repository source code and stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set up a Mockito mock for the repository and probably told it to return a `MySupportedKey` instance when `findById` gets called. 
But since `findById` is supposed to return an `Optional` you now get the exception.

You can see that this is coming from Mockito in the very first two lines of the stack trace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.service.user.entity.MySupportedKey cannot be cast to java.util.Optional
at com.test.service.user.repository.MySupportedKeyRepository$MockitoMock$1304362870.findById(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Thanks. You were right. I managed to get this thing working with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the *`Optional`*  handling in your below method to get the correct representation like below:

```
private MySupportedKey getSupportedKey(String tenant, String key) {
            Optional<MySupportedKey> mySupportedKeyOptional = mySupportedKeyRepository.findById(new MySupportedKeyId(tenant, key));
            MySupportedKey mySupportedKey= null;
            if(mySupportedKeyOptional.isPresent()) {
                 mySupportedKey= mySupportedKeyOptional.get();
            }
            return mySupportedKey;
        }
```

Comment: If the intent is really to convert the Optional to a null value it should be enough to simply return mySupportedKeyRepository.findById(new MySupportedKeyId(tenant, key)).orElse(null); But in my eyes this contradicts the basic idea of an Optional at all.

Comment: @C.Weber Agree with you, in such cases the use of optional must be diligently handled to represent a scenario based object creation representing nothing but the actual result of computation, like in above it could be object with intent as No data found?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot add comment, just wanted to elaborate on Jens answer since it took me a while to figure out how to fix this (being a newbie).
To fix the issue I changed my code from:

```
when(mongoRepository.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<MongoObj>() {
        @Override
        public MongoObj answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            MongoObj repush = new MongoObj();
            //Some other code

            return repush;
        }
    });
```

To

```
when(mongoRepository.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Optional<MongoObj>>() {
        @Override
        public Optional<MongoObj> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            MongoObj repush = new MongoObj();
            //Some other code

            return Optional.of(repush);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!